# I want to get result in one line. I don't need new dimensions

Tags: j

```
   (1:)`(3:)@.(1&=)"0 i.2
1 3
   (1:,2:)`(3:)@.(1&=)"0 i.2
1 2
3 0
```

I want to get

```
1 2 3
```

Without new dimensions. Without zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape changes dramatically between `(1:)` and `(1:,2:)`.

```
   $ 1: 'a'

   $ 1 $ 1: 'a'
1
   $ (1:,2:) 'a'
2
   (1&$ 1:)`(1&$ 3:)@.(1&=)"0 i.2
1
3
```

There's probably a better way, but to my way of thinking, you're generating arrays of unequal length, which should be boxed, and then you want to turn them into a single list.

Thus:

```
   ; ((1:,2:)`(3:))@.(1&=)"0&.> i.2
1 2 3
```

Which can be refactored and improved a bit:

```
   ;@:((1:,2:)`(3:)@.(1&=)each) i.2
1 2 3
```

Comment: each=: &.> and has an implied rank of 0 so that you can remove the "0                         ;@:((1:,2:)`(3:)@.(1&=)each) i.2

Comment: I think potentially what you're trying to do would be more naturally done in J as follows: `; (1 2;3) {~ 1 = i.2`

Answer (score 0):

You could have used `(1:,2:,3:) 'ignored argument'` to form the list, but that doesn't address why you were using `@.`

Dane's comment about boxing intermediate results and then razing the resulting list is relevant if you want to merge irregularly shaped results. (Which might be what you were trying for, here.)